# Laravel Singleton still creating new objects

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I have a singleton setup in my `AppServiceProvider.php`, such as this:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->singleton(Breadcrumbs::class, function($app){
        return new Breadcrumbs();
    });

    View::composer(['partials.*'], function($view){
        $view->with('breadcrumbs', new Breadcrumbs());
    });

}
```

Breadcrumbs is just a simple class that manages an array of breadcrumbs and I want there only to be 1 object across the whole app (so every time you call `new Breadcrumbs()` you actually get the existing object, not a new one. (i think this is what singletons are for?)

But now have added this to the `JetStreamServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
{
        $this->configurePermissions();

        Fortify::loginView(function (){
            $breadcrumbs = new Breadcrumbs();
            $breadcrumbs->add('login','login.php');
            return view('auth.login');
        });
}
```

However instead of using the same object as what was created in the AppServiceProvider it is making a new object (so the breadcrumbs object in AppServiceProvider and the breadcrumbs object in the JetStreamServiceProvider are 2 different objects containing a different set of data)...which is no good.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to resolve the binding you setup you need to use the IoC container that you set the binding on to resolve it. You calling `new Class` is you telling PHP directly to create a new instance of that class. Laravel does not change how PHP works.

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton(Breadcrumbs::class, function () { ... });
}

public function boot()
{
    View::composer(['partials.*'], function ($view) {
        // resolve the instance from the IoC (Application) Container
        $view->with('breadcrumbs', $this->app->make(Breadcrumbs::class));
    });

    // you can do a "view share" to share this with all views instead:
    View::share('breadcrumbs', $this->app->make(Breadcrumbs::class));
}



Fortify::loginView(function () {
    $this->app->make(Breadcrumbs::class)->add('login', 'login.php');
    return view('auth.login');
});
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Service Container - Resolving - The `make` method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#the-make-method)

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I used:

***AppServiceProvider***

```
public function register()
{
        $this->app->singleton(Breadcrumbs::class, function($app){
            return new Breadcrumbs();
        });
}

public function boot(Breadcrumbs $breadcrumbs)
{
        View::composer(['partials.*'], function($view) use ($breadcrumbs){
            $view->with('breadcrumbs', $breadcrumbs);
        });

}
```

***JetStreamServiceProvider.php***

```
public function boot(Breadcrumbs $breadcrumbs)
{
    Fortify::loginView(function () use ($breadcrumbs){
        $breadcrumbs->add('Login',Route('login'));
        return view('auth.login');
    });
}
```